# How to use Like operator for a variable in oracle trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I want to use `LIke` operator for a variable so here `:NEW.T2_NAME`, i tried like  `LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER( :NEW.T2_NAME, '%');` but it throws error,what is wrong here

```
create or replace 
trigger Testtrigger 
after INSERT OR UPDATE 
on Testtable 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
EQ__POWER_TRG VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
 SELECT EQ__POWER
    INTO EQ__POWER_TRG
    FROM T1
    WHERE UPPER(T1.NAME) LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER( :NEW.T2_NAME, '%');-- =UPPER( :NEW.T2_NAME);
 UPDATE T3
  SET EQ__POWER=EQ__POWER_TRG
 WHERE T_ID=ID;



  END IF;
    end;
```

Can any one tells me what is wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, the [`CONCAT()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) function only takes two arguments.  Use the tried, true and standard concatenation operator:

```
WHERE UPPER(T1.NAME) LIKE ('%' || UPPER(:NEW.T2_NAME) || '%');
```

Also, `UPPER()` only takes one argument.